# Java associations: How to convert String to another Class

Tags: java

I'm learning Java for school and started with a new chapter about associations. I have to make a program where 2 people enter their personal information and can marry. When I enter the name of the city, I get the error: "Expected: oef1_huwen.Gemeente (another exercise), Actual: java.lang.String. The city name has to be entered as a String but seen as Gemeente. Their information may only be entered using a constructor and I'm not allowed to use a setter for Gemeente.

I get an error on line 2 from HuwelijkApp

I really hope someone can help me, I'm studying for my exams right now... :s

Edit: Gemeente means city and Adres means address

This is some code from my class Persoon

```
package oef1_huwen;

public class Persoon {
    private String naam;
    private String voornaam;
    private Datum geboortedatum;
    private Adres adres;

public Persoon(String naam, String voornaam, int dag, int maand, int jaar, 
String straat, String huisnummer, int postcode, String gemeentenaam) {
    this.naam = naam;
    this.voornaam = voornaam;
    geboortedatum.setDag(dag);
    geboortedatum.setMaand(maand);
    geboortedatum.setJaar(jaar);
    adres.setStraat(straat);
    adres.setHuisNummer(huisnummer);
    adres.getGemeente().setPostcode(postcode);
    adres.getGemeente().setGemeenteNaam(gemeentenaam);
}

public Persoon(String naam, String voornaam, Datum geboortedatum, Adres 
adres) {
    this.naam = naam;
    this.voornaam = voornaam;
    this.geboortedatum = geboortedatum;
    this.adres = adres;

}
```

This is from my class Gemeente

```
package oef1_huwen;

public class Gemeente {
    private int postcode;
    private String gemeenteNaam;

public Gemeente(int postcode, String gemeenteNaam) {
    this.postcode = postcode;
    this.gemeenteNaam = gemeenteNaam;
}

public int getPostcode() {
    return postcode;
}

public void setPostcode(int postcode) {
    this.postcode = postcode;
}

public String getGemeenteNaam() {
    return gemeenteNaam;
}

public void setGemeenteNaam(String gemeenteNaam) {
    this.gemeenteNaam = gemeenteNaam;
}
```

Code from my class Adres:

```
package oef1_huwen;

public class Adres {
    private String straat;
    private String huisNummer;
    private Gemeente gemeente;

public Adres(String straat, String huisNummer, int postcode, Gemeente 
gemeente) {
    this.straat = straat;
    this.huisNummer = huisNummer;
    getGemeente().setPostcode(postcode);
    this.gemeente = gemeente;
}

public String getStraat() {
    return straat;
}

public void setStraat(String straat) {
    this.straat = straat;
}

public String getHuisNummer() {
    return huisNummer;
}

public void setHuisNummer(String huisNummer) {
    this.huisNummer = huisNummer;
}

public Gemeente getGemeente() {
    return gemeente;
}

public String toString() {
    return straat + " " + huisNummer + "\n" + gemeente;
}
```

}

And this is what I have in my class HuwelijkApp

```
Gemeente gemeente3 = new Gemeente(3290, "Diest");
Adres adres = new Adres("Kerkstraat", "12b", 3290, "Diest");
Persoon persoon = new Persoon("Aerts", "Jef", 29, 11, 1990, "Lindestraat", "23D", 3500, "Hasselt");
```

Comment: *When I enter the name of the city*: what does that mean? Your code doesn't ask anyoe to enter anything. It seems like you have a compilation error. What exact and complete error message do you get, and what precise lineof code does it refer to?

Comment: Can you show us `Gemeente`?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace please?

Comment: And you seem to be mixing languages between your question and your code. Which of those variable names translates to "city"?

Comment: JB Nizet When I enter "Diest" in my Adres constructor

Comment: mupetlion and Stalemate Of Tuning sure

Comment: mypetlion sorry you're right. Gemeente means city and Adres means address

Comment: Does `Gemeente` have a constructor that takes just a `String` argument?

Comment: Well, you didn't post the relevant code, but from the error message, we can say that the constructor expects a Gemeente as argument, but that you pass "Diest", which is a String. A String is not a Gemeente. So create a Gemeente, and pass that Gemeente as argument instead of "Diest". Since you have already created gemeente3, which is a Gemeente, you probably want to pass that.

Comment: Dawood ibn Kareem yes Gemeente just uses Strings

Comment: Ah, you say "yes", but I see from the code that you've just posted that the answer to my question was actually "no".

Comment: OK, I see no errors in the code you've posted.  Which line was the error reported on?

Comment: ohhh right I have overlooked int postcode

Comment: I get an error on line 2 from HuwelijkApp

Comment: So it looks like you're passing the wrong arguments to the constructor of `Adres`.  Have a look at the `Adres` class (which unfortunately you haven't posted) to see what the arguments _should_ be.

Comment: I told you 6 minutes ago what was wrong and what you had to do to fix the problem, but apparently you didn't read the comment.

Comment: Alright guys thank you I found the error

Comment: It was what JB Nizet said

Answer (score 1):

Can you alter your `Persoon` constructor? You have parameters `int postcode` and `String gemeentenaam`, but you could instead make one parameter `Gemeente gemeentenaam` and add a new instance of `Gemeente`. The `Gemeente` constructor takes in the same two parameters.